# WSO2 ESB Send attachment with Soap

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Tested soap with attachment Axis 2 server sample soapWithAttachment service  using soap UI client; any attachments formats jpeg, png, xml can be uploaded successfully through soap UI. Below is the input soap xml used to post in Soap UI and attached the attachment to the soap UI and post it. How this can be achieved through WSO2 ESB?

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ser="http://service.soapwithattachments.sample">
   <soap:Header/>
   <soap:Body>
      <ser:uploadFile>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:name>new2</ser:name>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ser:attchmentID>new13.xml</ser:attchmentID>
      </ser:uploadFile>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

As per my analysis client needs to process the file using data handler and generate the Attachment ID, this would be inbuilt for Soap UI; I would like to know how this can be achieved through WSO2 ESB without using custom Java mediator. I am using WSO2 version 4.9.0.  I have created the WSO2 ESB proxy as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="attachmentProxy"
       transports="https http"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <description/>
   <target faultSequence="fault">
      <inSequence>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/soapWithAttachment"
                        optimize="mtom"/>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="http://localhost:8080/axis2/services/soapWithAttachment?wsdl"/>
</proxy>
```